# how to run batch process for vector shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.0, vector-tiles, suitability-analysis

I am kind of new at this.

I ran a gis operation using python, where by I performed euclidean distance for specific state road, river and towns data and reclassified them showing good and bad areas and it worked.

However when I try to run batch processing for two state fils in the same folder, it runs but no output. any ideas how i can batch process vector files before reclassifying the raster output

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env   
from arcpy.sa import * 
import os

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
 # raise a custom exception
    raise LicenseError


if arcpy.CheckExtension("3D") == "Available":
   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
else:
 # raise a custom exception
   raise LicenseError
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
else:
 # raise a custom exception
   raise LicenseError


if arcpy.CheckExtension("3D") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
else:
 # raise a custom exception
    raise LicenseError 

env.workspace = "D:\\states\\ritchie"
root_folder = "D:\\states\\ritchie"
env.overwriteOutput=1

river = "C:\\states\\ritchie\\river\\"
try:
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcs:
        outEucDistance = EucDistance(os.path.join(river,fc), 2000, 50)
        outEucDistance.save("D:\\states\\ritchie\\river\\")
except:
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: hi, am not trying to get an output for one file(state), but i want to get for 2 files in the river folder at the same time. and i have just specified output.save to the river folder on my end, still no result. any ideas please

Comment: Are you sure `"2 kilometers"` is correct? That is shouldnt be `"2 Kilometers"`, or `2000`? If you remove the `try/except` you will get error messages telling you stuff like this.

Comment: still no result or error message

Comment: ok i will do that now

Comment: You are not getting any errors becuase you are still using `try/except`, dont… This `outEucDistance.save("D:\\states\\ritchie\\river\\")` does not look like a valid output. Try `outEucDistance.save("D:\\states\\ritchie\\river\\somerastername")`

Comment: but there are two shapefile in ritchie folder and i want to run the process for both files in the folder at the same time, so if i write an output path for one file, what would i do for the other

Comment: Something like `outEucDistance.save("D:\\states\\ritchie\\river\\Outraster_{0}".format(fc.split('.')[0])` to name output by input shapefile (without `.shp`)